# How does DoorDash build their marketing attribution forecasting model?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, forecasting, marketing

I was reading this [blog](https://doordash.engineering/2021/08/10/predicting-marketing-performance-from-early-attribution-indicators/) post about DoorDash's new attribution forecast model that predicts an ad’s final conversion volume after observing only its initial data.

I am wondering how they built it.

They say that - 'The approach we chose was to build a forecasting model that predicts final attribution data from a limited amount of initial data.'

Its a little unclear to me how they could have built this with incomplete data. Would they be sampling some new data or predicting the incomplete data?

Comment: I can't say with certainty, but my read on the situation from what you provided is that they regress final conversion volume on initial conversion volume.  E.g. you can predict the total volume after 30 days from observing the first 14 days